# Is //(typeof(myVar) != "undefined")// logically equivalent to the truthy //if (myVar)?

Tags: javascript, truthiness

Over a large project I do a lot of exception handling by explicitly checking whether a variable has been set using typeof. It's a bit verbose and I'd like to change my habit to a simple truthy:

```
if (myVar) {//do stuff}
```

In the snippet below and in some other tests they appear to be equivalent. Before I doing sweeping code changes however (and replace hundreds of these) I'd like to confirm they're logically equivalent and learn about any edge cases that might get me.

```js
//What I have been doing

let myVar;

{
//other code that may or may not be able to give myVar a value 
}

if (typeof(myVar) != "undefined"){
  console.log("the value has been set, do more stuff");
} else {
  console.log("the value was not set, handle the exception path");
}

//What I'd like to do

if (myVar) {
  console.log("the value has been set, do more stuff");
} else {
  console.log("the value was not set, handle the exception path");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```js
if (myVar) {}
```

will return false on **all falsy values**, like empty string (`""`), zero (`0`), `false`, `null`, and of course, `undefined`.

If you do not expect any of the above values to pass through your `if` statement, then yes, it is logically equivalent.

But, I would say that this is a **bold** statement that none of your `if` statements will contain `0` or `""`. These are common values.

If you want to cleanup this code and continue to only check for `undefined`, then you can skip the typecheck and just check with:

```js
if (myVar === undefined) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

They can look that way, but might not turn out as your expect.

Here some further proof:

```js
const tests = [false, undefined, null, '', NaN, 0, -0, 0n, 'anything else'];
tests.map(t=> console.log(t ? t + ' is truthy' : t + ' is falsy'));
```

Answer (score 0):

No.
Because in this case `if(myVar)` if `myVar = 0, false, "",undefined` will be return false. And `if (typeof(myVar) != "undefined")` just return false when `myVar = undefined`

Answer (score 0):

With exclamation sign you can check that variable to the opossite boolean value, for example undefined, false, an empty string, null and 0 are falsy values

```js
let myVar = undefined;
if(!myVar){
    console.log('type of: ' + typeof(myVar))
}   

myVar = '';
if(!myVar){
    console.log('type of: ' + typeof(myVar))
}   

myVar = false;
if(!myVar){
    console.log('type of: ' + typeof(myVar))
}
```